# Why doesn't all-auth provide adapters for OpenID based providers?

Tags: django, django-allauth, django-rest-auth

I have a django app on the server side providing REST APIs to the client. I want to enable a user to connect his Steam and Facebook accounts to his django account.

For Facebook connect, it is straightforward, I used [Django-Rest-Auth for this](https://django-rest-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#additional-social-connect-views).

```
from allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook.views import FacebookOAuth2Adapter

class FacebookConnect(SocialConnectView):
    adapter_class = FacebookOAuth2Adapter
```

But there is no adapter for [Steam](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/allauth/socialaccount/providers/steam/views.py) or any other [OpenID](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/allauth/socialaccount/providers/openid/views.py) based provider.

How can I create a REST API for client to be able to connect user's Steam account

Comment: I don't understand, django-allauth has [steam support](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/providers.html#steam) out of the box. And any other [openID](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/providers.html#openid) provider.

Comment: They have provided a [SteamOpenIDCallbackView and SteamOpenIDLoginView](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/allauth/socialaccount/providers/steam/views.py) which will render a html page. I want to build REST APIs for the same functionality.

Comment: How about subclassing those views, just overriding the returned content to be the json you want? It's just a matter of overriding `get` and `post`, setting `response = super().get/post` and returning whatever you need to return in json.

Comment: I'm trying to do something similar, hope luck finds me. Thanks for the advise @dirkgroten